# How to change the color of btn-default

Tags: css

The btn-default color is white.But I am unable to change the color of the btn-default

```
<div class="pageOne">
    <h1 class="text-center" id="header_text"> a Good Tree production </h1>
    <div class="btnList">
        <a class="btn btn-default" href = "#"> a Good Tree production</a>
        <a class="btn btn-default" href = "#"> About Us</a>
        <a class="btn btn-default" href = "#"> Contact Us</a>
        <a class="btn btn-default" href = "#"> Works</a>
   </div>
</div>
```

Here is the CSS

```
.btn-default{
    background-color: black !important;
}
#header_text{
    font-family: 'Boogaloo', cursive;
    color: white !important;
}
```

Could anyone help me with this.

Comment: Works for me http://www.bootply.com/KFcqllfiQN

Answer (score 0):

The Bootstrap CSS is overriding yours. You need to provide a higher-level CSS selector, like:

```
#header_text .btn-default {
  background-color: black !important;
}
```

This is higher-level than the Bootstrap selector, which is:

```
.btn.btn-default {
  /* Whatever their CSS is */
}
```

Comment: .btn.btn-default{
 background-color: black !important;
}
#header_text{
 font-family: 'Boogaloo', cursive;
 color: white !important;
 } but still it's not working

Comment: Right, didn't notice the `!important`.  I don't see any reason why it's not working, maybe you should check to see if your CSS is actually showing up. Do you have a live version we could look at?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/VijayVj7/trbddvet/1/    this is link for live output